# WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH! Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242258/warning:-current-working-directory-is-not-on-ros_package_path!-please-update-your-ros_package_path-environment-variable./) by [Gabriel1](https://answers.ros.org/users/27822/gabriel1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-23

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to source your environment before you try to use ROS.

```
source /opt/ros/YOUR_ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash or .zsh or.sh depending on your shell.
```

Also, when you try something within your workspace, you need to source the setup files in your devel folder, same logic as above:

```
source CURRENT_WORKING_WS/devel/setup.bash
```

See this for more info :

[www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2